# What kind of star does Jupiter become?

Tags: 2001-a-space-odyssey, 2010-odyssey-two

In *2010: Odyssey Two* Jupiter is turned into a star, but what kind of star is it turning into?

Comment: An artificial one. Not one on the main scale.

Comment: @Valorum Wouldn't it follow that other stars we currently observe also be artificial? So even though it's artificial it might still fit into categories of observed stars.

Comment: @Toddwilcox - Possibly, but there's nothing in the films/books to suggest it.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Not really, no - the definitions of stars are based primarily on their mass, and Jupiter isn't anywhere close to the mass of a star.

Comment: The book would indicate that it's a really bloody weird one; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93646/why-didnt-jupiter-becoming-a-star-kill-everyone-on-earth-and-cause-all-kinds-of

Comment: Doesn't it burn through its fuel in 1000 years?  I vaguely remember an "epilogue" paragraph-or-so making a statement to that effect, but don't remember if Odyssey 3001 mentions it.

Comment: @Werrf Once the aliens are done with it, what mass does the new star have? At the risk of trying to inject real-world science into science fiction, one possible explanation for what happened when Jupiter was turned into a star was that the aliens used monoliths to add mass to Jupiter. So we could ask how much mass did they add and therefore what kind of star is it? Aside from that, if no other observed stars are also artificial, then somehow humans are unique in the whole universe that we have the only artificial star in our own system. That seems unlike the rest of the story.

Comment: @ToddWilcox That is a possibility, but if so it was not mentioned in the film or the book. It would also make the star more powerful, and thus more likely to wipe out the life on Europa that it was supposed to be nurturing.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Adding mass to Jupiter without speeding up its moons would destroy the entire planetary system. The balance of satellite orbit speed/time and distance to the main body is dependent on the main body's mass. If you increase the central mass (increase gravitational force between planet and moon) without increasing the satellite speeds (increasing the outward force) they would all fall into the central mass.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Also, increasing Jupiter's mass enough so natural stellar fusion would occur would destroy the other planets' orbits in the solar system. Certainly those of Mars and Saturn, most likely Earth's orbit as well.

Comment: @ToddWilcox The book explicitly states that the monoliths did not add mass to Jupiter - the first monolith replicated like a virus using Jupiter's mass and increased its density by reducing Jupiter's volume (size), thus concentrating that same mass in a smaller space.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While it's common, especially in sci-fi and popular science, to call Jupiter a "failed star", it's rather a misleading description. Let's look at some stars...

### Brown Dwarfs

The smallest objects science considers "stars" are [brown dwarfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_dwarf). These are objects that are not massive enough to fuse ordinary hydrogen in their cores, but can fuse *deuterium*, an isotope of hydrogen that has a single neutron in its nucleus (ordinary hydrogen doesn't have any neutrons). Of all stellar bodies, these are the closest to Jupiter's mass - but even the smallest brown dwarf has AT LEAST 13 times the mass of Jupiter.

### Red Dwarfs

Next up in the scale, and arguably the smallest 'true' stars, are [red dwarfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_dwarf) (no, not the [mining ship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Dwarf_spacecraft#Red_Dwarf)). These range from about 0.075 solar masses to around 0.5 solar masses, and they're the smallest stars that exist on the Main Sequence.

For comparison, Jupiter's mass is 0.001 solar masses.

Mass is the critical component here. It's the gravitational energy from the enormous mass of even the smallest stars that compresses them enough to sustain nuclear fusion. Jupiter's mass isn't even close to high enough for that

### If we can't use mass, how about temperature?

Well, there's bad news there, too...

Europa's average orbit around Jupiter is around 670,000 km. That would change a bit with the reduction in Jupiter's own diameter when it became Lucifer, so let's round up to something like 700,000 km. How *hot* would Lucifer have to be for Europa to be in its habitable zone?

[Here](http://depts.washington.edu/naivpl/sites/default/files/hz.shtml) is a habitable zone calculator. It returns the size in AU of the habitable zone for a star with a given temperature and luminosity. That unit, AU, gives us the first clue of how much trouble we're in. 1 AU is equal to the distance from the Earth to the sun, around 149,600,000 km. Europa's orbit equals roughly 0.004 AU.

I played with the numbers in the calculator a little bit. To get a habitable zone of 0.003 AU, I reduced the star's temperature to 1,000 kelvin, and 0.00001 times the luminosity of the sun.

These numbers are *just* in the range for a very cool, very dim brown dwarf (though most measures of luminosity don't go anywhere near that low). That's probably the closest to an answer we'll see.

The trouble is, of course, that Lucifer was supposed to light the night side of Earth; a very dim brown dwarf would be little brighter than the planet Jupiter, and wouldn't have anything like that great an effect.

It seems that there is no good answer - a star that could light the night side of Earth from Jupiter's orbit could not also sustain life on a moon as close as Europa. While Arthur C. Clarke's writing was generally very scientifically literate, on this one he just didn't get the numbers right.

Comment: It was visible from Earth during the height of daytime. That doesn't suggest "Brown Dwarf" to me.

Comment: @Valorum It also didn't immediately incinerate Europa; going any brighter would do that. Unlike a lot of Clarke's writing, this one just really isn't feasible.

Comment: Another problem is the mass/temperature balance. Fusion occurs when a mass of hydrogen collapses under its own gravity. The fusion heats up the hydrogen and creates an expanding force. This creates (an ever-changing) equilibrium. Without extra mass (as stated in the book) there is an upper limit to the temperature Lucifer could have, and thus an upper limit to the luminosity. There is no possible way that a Jupiter-sized mass could *continuously* generate that much light.

Comment: @Hans it doesn't. About 100 years later, the star goes out (see the epilogue of the book mentioned in the comment).

Comment: I'm happy with this answer

Comment: @MarkGardner Damn, you're correct. Although it's 1,000 years later, in 3001 (which is the title of the epilogue). Just confirmed it in my copy of *2061: Odyssey 3*. (In Dutch, meaning I bought and read it at the time of publication in 1988. This will have been one of the last translated books I ever bought or read.) But that contradicts the "creating life" bit of firing up Lucifer. A thousand years is not enough for any kind of major evolution.

Comment: @Hans Firstly the life on Europa was already well-developed by the time of 2010, but it couldn't develop any further because of the ice. Secondly, the original book's epilogue was *20,001*, which gives the Europans much more time. Thirdly, there was a Monolith on Europa from the start, accelerating their development.

Comment: It's been so long since I read the books and I haven't reread them because they're in Dutch. And wasn't there a statement by Clarke that the individual books weren't necessarily in the same universe? I think we can at least agree that the physics of Lucifer are impossible in any of those universes. Also, Europa is an ice-covered ocean without an atmosphere. Any life would have been aquatic and, again, 1,000 (or 20,000) years is not enough for any major evolution out of that aquatic environment. (Now I want to watch *Europa Report* again, and then reread Baxter's *Titan*.)

Comment: That all depends upon how good the monoliths are at maintaining the reaction they started. As Arthur C. Clarke himself once said, "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic."